# How to get info about cookie and GET parameter in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to first try to retrieve `$_COOKIE[a]`,if it's not available then retrieve `$_GET['a']`

How to do this in actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE & $_GET being PHP variables, you would typically use PHP to retrieve those values with a PHP script that would return those values to Actionscript. There are a lot of resources out there for Flash/ Php communication.

Check this , for instance
http://code2design.com/tutorial/sending_variables_from_flash_to_php_and_back

Answer (score 0):

The `stage` and document object will have a `loaderInfo` property. `LoaderInfo` has a `parameters` attribute which is an object of the query-string parameters passed to the script via the file reference (file.swif?**query=string**). For a larger parameter length, you can use `<param name="flashvars" value="query=string" />` as it can contain any length of characters (vs the cap of 65535 chars for a path).

You may need to listen for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event to fire before the stage and parameters are accessible via ActionScript.

There are a number of ways to get cookies in flash.

1. You can request data from a the server using a `URLLoader`. The data can contain the cookie information.
2. You can request data from JavaScript using `ExternalInterface.call()`. This will allow you to get/set the current cookie information with JavaScript.
3. You can use ActionScript's native `LocalSharedObject` aka "Flash Cookie" to store information. Be very careful of how much data storage you need and what information you store about a user.

Comment: Can you give an example how get query string from `LoaderInfo` ?

Comment: if you've sent "query=string", "stage.loaderInfo.parameters.query" will have a value of "string".